# Installing nicematrix in texmaker macOS

Tags: texmaker, texmf, nicematrix

I asked a question today in [Trying to personalize this code for block matrices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586133/trying-to-personalize-this-code-for-block-matrices)
, where the suggestion was to use the nicematrix package.

The readme file in https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix suggests generating a .sty file and pasting it in the .tex folder, which I already did, but it still doesn't compile. Another option is pasting the folder in a `texmf` tree. I created a folder called `texmf` in my  `~/Library` folder, pasted the .sty file, but the code still doesn't compile.

Where is the `texmf` tree located?

I am using texmaker.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You mentioned you're using texmaker, but what TeX distribution are you using? If you installed MacTeX with all the packages, then `nicematrix` should already be present and ready to be used, with a simple `\usepackage{nicematrix}`. There generally should be no reason to manually download the package from CTAN.

Comment: If you're under MacTeX, why don't you install it with `TeX Live Utility`?